# Regex match User ID with comma's

Tags: regex

I am matching User ID's with regex (in Splunk) and encountered mixed results:

**Regex**              `^[^=\n]*`

https://regexr.com/4mn3d

**Splunk Extraction** `^[^=\n]*=(?P<user>[^ ]+)`

**Rules/Test Data**

- firstname.lastname
- A123456
- domain-name\firstname.lastname
- domain-name\A123456
- lastname, firstname
- lastname, firstname initial

**Log sample**

`Oct  3 23:33:00 2019 wc1 authmgr[4111]: <522008> <4904> <NOTI> <wc1 123.134.128.122>  User Authentication Successful: username=lastname, firstname MAC=d0:c6:25:79:e7:c6 IP=192.168.16.26 role=Authenticated VLAN=600 AP=43:4a:e3:c9:ec:0c SSID=corpnet AAA profile=aaaprof auth method=802.1x auth server=authserv`

`Oct  3 22:42:27 2019 wc1 authmgr[4111]: <522008> <4111> <NOTI> <wc1 123.134.128.122>  User Authentication Successful: username=lastname, firstname initial MAC=b2:09:cf:4c:80:1e IP=192.168.16.27 role=Authenticated VLAN=600 AP=34:fc:b2:c1:be:dc SSID=corpnet AAA profile=aaaprof auth method=802.1x auth server=authserv`

**Expected**

`username=lastname, firstname`

`username=lastname, firstname initial`

The matches work on regex.com but the `lastname, firstname` doesn't match in Splunk. Seems like the current regex stop at the comma.

Comment: It is hard to help without having example data. Your code looks like it is expecting "`name=value`" but none of your test data does. Please [edit] your question to give actual example input data and expected output data. We.need a [mcve].

Comment: It doesn't stop at comma, it stops at first space (after `lastname,`)

Comment: Apologies, yes that's right.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your Regex works in one place but not in another could be due to different Regex flavors/engines used in [regexr.com](https://www.regexr.com) and Splunk.

The following Regex should work for your use case:
`^[^=]*=([^=]*)(?=\s)`

However, the username must not contain an equals sign for the Regex to work. This can be achieved by sanitizing the user input to alphanumerics plus the special characters you specified (".", "\", spaces), etc.

```js
const logEntries = `Oct  3 23:33:00 2019 wc1 authmgr[4111]: <522008> <4904> <NOTI> <wc1 123.134.128.122>  User Authentication Successful: username=lastname, firstname MAC=d0:c6:25:79:e7:c6 IP=192.168.16.26 role=Authenticated VLAN=600 AP=43:4a:e3:c9:ec:0c SSID=corpnet AAA profile=aaaprof auth method=802.1x auth server=authserv

Oct  3 22:42:27 2019 wc1 authmgr[4111]: <522008> <4111> <NOTI> <wc1 123.134.128.122>  User Authentication Successful: username=lastname, firstname initial MAC=b2:09:cf:4c:80:1e IP=192.168.16.27 role=Authenticated VLAN=600 AP=34:fc:b2:c1:be:dc SSID=corpnet AAA profile=aaaprof auth method=802.1x auth server=authserv`;

let result;

logEntries.split(/\n/).map((entry) => {
  result = entry.match(/^[^=]*=([^=]*)(?=\s)/);

  if (result) {
    console.log(result[1]);
  }
});
```

In the above example, note that I first split the log into separate entries and then ran the Regex match individually on each.

An explanation of the Regex:

`^` - asserts position at start of a line
`[^=]` - matches anything that's not a literal equals sign (=)
`*` - matches between zero and unlimited times
`=` - matches a literal equals sign
`([^=]*)` - a capture group that matches anything that's not a literal equals sign
`(?=\s)` - a positive lookahead asserting that what immediately follows the current position in the string is a space character

Comment: Thank you.  I tried this too in Splunk but the same situation, stops after the first space (after lastname,). Your demo looks correct tho...

Comment: @pablo808 Could it be that the character after "lastname," is not actually a space? Try pasting the text from the log directly into a tool that shows non-printable characters: https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php  

A space character will be represented by the code "0x20".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I well understand your needs, but is this what you want:

```
(\w+)=(.+?)(?=\s\w+=|$)
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/TAT7gb/1)

Comment: Even your demo works and appears right, in Splunk is stop after the first space (after lastname,).

Comment: @pablo808: May be Splunk doesn't support lookahead. Have a try with `(\w+)=(.+?)(\s|$)` or  `(\w+)=(.+?)(?:\s|$)`

Comment: No joy.  I think you might be right.  Thanks for your help anyway.  Really appreciate it.

Comment: @pablo808: Are there some error logs or similar that can explain why it didn't work?